# WAMP php ODBC Connection 'Warning'

Tags: php, odbc, wamp, sqlanywhere

I have a problem with ODBC in php (WAMP Server 2.5, PHP 5.5.12).

When I try to run:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("odbc_dsn", "user", "pwd");

if ($conn) 
{
    echo "Connection established.";
} 
else
{
    exit("Connection could not be established.");
}
```

I get a Warning:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\Concepts\index.php on line 29

Connection could not be established.
```

If I change the "odbc_dsn" to something else (that doesn't exist) like "fdbasdf" then I get:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben, 
SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\Concepts\index.php on line 

Connection could not be established.
```

(Translated)

```
The Data Source could not be  found, and no default driver is given.
```

This tells me that the first execution was able to find the db, but did not open it... Why?

Is this another config thing? Is it trying to execute Client-Side? What can I do?

Comment: Add the drivers like `odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)});`

Comment: I've tried that already after surfing around, but couldn't get it working (maybe my syntax is wrong?). But the thing I don't get here is that the Driver, Server, and DB are defined on the ODBC. Why do I need to specify it all again? Whats the point of having an ODBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the Host and Connect protocol:

```
$connect_string =  "Driver={SQL Anywhere 12};".
                   "CommLinks=tcpip(Host=$db_host);".
                   "ServerName=$db_server_name;".
                   "DatabaseName=$db_name;";

// Connect to DB

$conn = odbc_connect( $connect_string, $db_user, $db_pass );
```