# PHP : Warning : Changed database context Using odbc_data_source

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm having the following error :

> Warning: odbc_data_source(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'Database'., SQL state 01000 in SQLDataSources in MyFile

With the following sample :

```
$conn = odbc_connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyComputer;Database=DataBase;', 'sa', 'sa');
$result = odbc_data_source($conn, SQL_FETCH_FIRST);
```

I don't have this issue using :

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM RandomTable");
```

I already know that this isn't a fatal error and we can live with, but I'd like to have a cleaner code.

So, what is the right way to use *odbc_data_source* without having this error message ?

I'm trying this code on WampServer using PHP 5.6.25. The database(s) targeted is(are) hosted on SQLServer Express 11.0.2100.60

Comment: possible duplicate of :- [php ODBC Connection Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248995/4248328)

Comment: @AlivetoDie, thx for your answer.
 I tried to add the protocol in the DSN :
`$conn = odbc_connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:192.168.XXX.XXX,1433;Database=DB;', 'Name', 'password');

$result = odbc_data_source($conn, SQL_FETCH_FIRST );`

Still have the same issue

Comment: `$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=localhost;Database=DB;", $user, $password);` pass correct dbname username and password in this

Comment: tried with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as Driver. The warning remains. I don't think it comes from the connection, I've a lot of functionnalities based on odbc_exect that are working very well. The first meeting with the Warning has been at the first use of odbc_data_source